# iphone-Xcode 5 xib/storyboard Problems

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xib, xcode5

Okay- I have this space shooter app based on uiimageviews. Originally, I made it on Xcode 3. Then, I converted it to Xcode 4. However, I did not use story mode. I stuck with the .xib files and it worked fine after I edited some of the basic code around. Then, when Xcode 5 came out, I couldn't do that anymore. When I tested my app on the iPad, most of the screen was grey and only the top corner had my game in it. I would like it to be able to auto size using just the xib files. Also, with the 4 inch and 3.5 inch iPhones, how can i make a view that fits them all? I tried storyboard, but my app was based on .xib files. It is one view controller, but it loads a lot of different .xib 's. What is my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to switch your app from universal to just iPhone.

Comment: And how is that going to help if you actually want to have a universal app?

Comment: The app can still load on an iPad just fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can find a solution to a problem, similar to the one you are having, in the following stackoverflow [How to convert a project using XIBs to Storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458072/how-to-convert-a-project-using-xibs-to-storyboard)

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful. Please try to add the essentials to your answer.